# What is the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1-2+3-4+\cdots+(-2n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1-2+3-4+\cdots+(-2n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}.$$

I thought to apply squeeze theorem so 
$$\frac{1-2+3-4+\cdots+(-2n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\leq \frac{1+2+3+4+\cdots+(2n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\frac{n(2n+1)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$ But I am unable to find a lower bound though. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following. For any $k$ we have $$1-2+3-4 + ... +(-2k) = (1-2) + (3-4) + \cdots +(2k-1 - 2k) =-k$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)-\sum_{k=1}^n (2k)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)\\\\
&=-n
\end{align}$$

Then, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}k=-1$$